# copy rows in Excel VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to copy three specific rows from `ActiveSheet` and want to paste/insert those three ranges based on `ColorIndex`.

```
 Dim last1Row As Long, J As Long

Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("sheet1")  'set you data sheet here
last1Row = ws.Cells(Rows.Count, "M").End(xlUp).Row  'get the last row in column A
For J = last1Row To 7 Step -1    'loop from last row to row 2
    If ws.Range("M" & J).Interior.ColorIndex = 37 Then
      ws.Range("M" & J + 2).EntireRow.Insert
        ws.Rows("4:4").Copy
        ws.Range("M" & J + 2).EntireRow.Insert
          ws.Rows("3:3").Copy
         ws.Range("M" & J + 2).EntireRow.Insert
         ws.Rows("1:1").Copy

         ws.Range("M" & J + 2).EntireRow.Insert

       ws.Rows("5:5").Copy


    End If
Next J
```

Comment: Is this code doing the Job ? or showing an error ?

Comment: its doing the job but painfully slow. thinking about some kind of loop but can not come up with any since i am specifying rows

Comment: Please tidy up first. Please begin with homogeneous code indentation. Remove typos, eg "last1Row" vs. "last1Row" / last row in column A or M ? Please use `Option Explicit` as first code line in each module. Use `.Cells(J, "M") instead of `.Range("M" & J)`, `ws.Rows(3)` instead of `ws.Rows("3:3")`

Answer (score 0):

**Try This:**

```
Dim last2Row As Long
Dim J As Integer

Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("sheet1")

last2Row = ws.Cells(Rows.Count, "M").End(xlUp).Row

For J = last2Row To 7 Step -1
    If ws.Range("M" & J).Interior.ColorIndex = 37 Then

        ws.Range("M" & J + 2).EntireRow.Insert
        ws.Rows("3:4").Copy
        ws.Range("M" & J + 2).EntireRow.Insert
        ws.Rows("1:1").Copy
        ws.Range("M" & J + 2).EntireRow.Insert
        ws.Rows("5:5").Copy


    End If
Next J
```